# what does mouseover call mean here?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tooltip

why is the mouseover method called again at the end of attaching plugin at this code:

```
$("[id^=pane]").delegate("[id^=comm]:not(.hastooltip)","mouseover",function() {
       $(this).addClass("hastooltip").tooltip({
          tip: "#tooltip",
          position: "bottom center",
          offset: [-10, 0],
          delay: 0
       }).mouseover();

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

The function is called if the delegate does not have the ".hastooltip" class.  Calling mouseover() forces the function to trigger and add the ".hastooltip" class.